# Specify the exact order in brunch-config.js of compiling into app.(css, js)

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I have this in the brunch-config file:

```
stylesheets: {
  joinTo: "app.css",
  order: {
    before: ["web/static/css/1.css",
             "web/static/css/2.css",
             "web/static/css/3.css"],
    after: ["web/static/css/app.css"]
  }
},
```

It seems those 3 files get compiled into app.css in an arbitrary order, whereas I want the order to be the same as I've specified: 1, 2 and 3.css How can I do that?

Comment: I'm getting the correct order here with that config.